# how to send mails asynchronous?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sendmail, smtpclient

```
namespace Binarios.admin
{
    public class SendEmailGeral
    {
        public SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        public MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

        public void Enviar(string sendFrom, string sendTo, string subject, string body)
        {    
            string pass = "12345";
            System.Net.NetworkCredential smtpCreds = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(sendFrom, pass);

            //setup SMTP Host Here
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = smtpCreds;
            client.EnableSsl = true;

            MailAddress to = new MailAddress(sendTo);
            MailAddress from = new MailAddress(sendFrom);

            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            msg.Subject = subject;
            msg.Body = body;
            msg.From = from;
            msg.To.Add(to);

            client.Send(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

I've this code, but i'd like to improve it in way that i could send mails asynchronous.
Could you suggest any idea to improve this piece of code or other way to do it.
I've tried asynchronous properties that visual studio suggested but couldn't use them.

Comment: Have you actually looked at the documentation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h.aspx

Comment: Try searching before??? [Asynchronously sending Emails in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408397/asynchronously-sending-emails-in-c) .. [Two ways to send email via SmtpClient asynchronously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768863/two-ways-to-send-email-via-smtpclient-asynchronously-different-results)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`SmtpClient` allows you to send asynchronously, and uses events to notify you when the send completes. This can be unweildy to use, so you can create an extension method to return a `Task` instead:

```
public static Task SendAsync(this SmtpClient client, MailMessage message)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    Guid sendGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

    SendCompletedEventHandler handler = null;
    handler = (o, ea) =>
    {
        if (ea.UserState is Guid && ((Guid)ea.UserState) == sendGuid)
        {
            client.SendCompleted -= handler;
            if (ea.Cancelled)
            {
                tcs.SetCanceled();
            }
            else if (ea.Error != null)
            {
                tcs.SetException(ea.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                tcs.SetResult(null);
            }
        }
    };

    client.SendCompleted += handler;
    client.SendAsync(message, sendGuid);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

To get the result of the send task you can use `ContinueWith`:

```
Task sendTask = client.SendAsync(message);
sendTask.ContinueWith(task => {
    if(task.IsFaulted) {
        Exception ex = task.InnerExceptions.First();
        //handle error
    }
    else if(task.IsCanceled) {
        //handle cancellation
    }
    else {
        //task completed successfully
    }
});
```

Comment: this is giving me an error now, it says: Failure sending mail.

Comment: @DiogoSeveriano - Firstly, there was a bug in the code I initially posted which would cause a stack overflow exception. If you're using the current version of the code, you should be able to get the inner exception from the task when it completes. What's the exception?

Comment: i solved the problem with Async="true" in the page, that was the problem, but now i think this doesn't send asynchronous because i still have to wait to this to send the mails and then i can do something.

Comment: @DiogoSeveriano - You shouldn't have to wait for the `Task` to complete. Are you calling `Task.Wait()`? That will cause the current thread to block until the task completes. You should use `ContinueWith` to get the result of the task when it has completed. Alternatively you can use `await sendTask` if you're using C#5.

Comment: i'm not using anything else, unless what you gave to me.

Comment: SendAsync(client, msg); how can i use ContinueWith, i'm an amateur with threading

Comment: @DiogoSeveriano - I've updated the answer to include an example of using `ContinueWith`.

Comment: Your code will not work when somebody tries to send several e-mails simultaneously using the single SmtpClient.

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess, but [SendAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h.aspx) might do the job!

Answer (score 0):

Change your code from:

```
 client.Send(msg);
```

To:

```
client.SendAsync(msg);
```

more details

[link1](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SendSmtpAsync.aspx)

[link2](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-send-email-asynchronously-with-aspnet)

Comment: Failure sending mail. when using that.

Comment: @DiogoSeveriano, well *how* does it fail? Any errors? Does it silently fail? Does your computer catch fire? **How** does this not work?