# Async method takes about same response time as sync method for System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email, asynchronous

We're sending an email out when a particular MVC controller method is called. The code is as below. When benchmarking the AJAX response time inside a browser we see that the `client.SendAsync(mail, null)` and `client.Send(mail)` implementations BOTH take about the same time i.e. 1.8 seconds as compared to not sending the mail at all.

```
public ActionResult jsonPosted(int? id, SomeDataClass data)
{   
    ...

    // NOTE: remode 'using' statement for Async calls
    // else no email ever sees light
    using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
    {       
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("name@server.com", "password");
        client.Port = 587;
        client.Host = "smtp.server.com";
        client.EnableSsl = true;

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress("admin@server.com");
        mail.To.Add("sales@server.com");
        mail.Subject = "Coming soon: user " + newUser.Email + " registered on list";
        mail.Body = "Email address is : " + newUser.Email + "\n";
        mail.Body += "Date of signup is : " + newUser.SignupTime.ToString();

        try
        {
            // Both take about 1.9 seconds ?!?!
            //client.SendAsync(mail, null);
            client.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (SmtpException e)
        {
            // bad smtp, no mail for you
        }
    }
    ...
    return Json(dataIndependentOfEmail);
}
```

Question:

1. Why do the two methods take the same time? Async should return immediately while Sync should block for the entire processing time, right? As I understand Async consumes another thread and THAT thread blocks during work. However at least the user on the 1st thread should see a performance boost.
2. How does one properly use `using` to dispose off classes like `SmtpClient` and `MailMessage` in async mode?

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) for an msdn example on the async smtpclient.
In this example they are not using dispose as (and this is a minor guess) the using will wait on the async operation to complete.
For testing purposes try removing the using statement, i expect the sendAsync to be faster then the send.
Offcourse you're not dispoing the smtpclient object properly, one way to handle the disposing is to create a new thread which handles the email the old skool way. You wouldn't have the cleanness of SendAssync but at least you're sure that the user gets instant feedback + the smtpclient is disposed properly.
Edit: an even better solution is to use the event sendcompleted and dispose the smtpclient there.
see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276375/what-are-best-practices-for-using-smtpclient-sendasync-and-dispose-under-net-4) for an example