# SendAsync Smtp Mail Error

Tags: c#, smtp, sendasync

Application requires that a use SendAsync rather than just Send. So i Made a Class CEmailServer and set up everything. So far Send works fine but when changing it to work with SendAsync it does not. I Created a Method to be called when a mail is sent and the userToken is in place but it keeps failing. i Can't find my error. Here is my code :

```
static bool mailSent = false;

//Method for Sending with attachment.
public void SendEmail(string Address, string Recipient, string Subject, string Body, string Dir)
{
    var fromAddress = new MailAddress("someadress.kimberley@gmail.com", "My Company");
    var toAddress = new MailAddress(Address, Recipient);
    const string fromPassword = "password";
    string subject = Subject;
    string body = Body;

    var smtp = new SmtpClient
    {
        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
        Port = 587,
        EnableSsl = true,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)

    };
    using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
    {
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body,
    })
    {
        smtp.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);
        string userState = "Test";
        message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(Dir));
        smtp.SendAsync(message,userState);
        message.Dispose();
    }
}

//Method for Sending regular message without attachment.
public void SendEmail(string Address, string Recipient, string Subject, string Body)
{
    var fromAddress = new MailAddress("someadress.kimberley@gmail.com", "My Company");
    var toAddress = new MailAddress(Address, Recipient);
    const string fromPassword = "password";
    string subject = Subject;
    string body = Body;

    var smtp = new SmtpClient
    {
        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
        Port = 587,
        EnableSsl = true,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)

    };
    using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
    {
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body,
    })
    {
        smtp.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);
        string userState = "Message Sent";
        smtp.SendAsync(message, userState);
        message.Dispose();
    }
}

//Method to be called when sending is complete
private static void SendCompletedCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the unique identifier for this asynchronous operation.
    String token = (string)e.UserState;

    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Sending Canc");
    }
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error Sending Mail");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Message sent.");
    }
    mailSent = true;
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: I sincerely hope that is not your actual password.

Comment: Nope, old aacount thats been deleted

Comment: But just in case ill use different credentials :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are disposing the `message` before the send can complete. You should be disposing them in the `SendCompleted` callback event. Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7276819/517852) of the best way to dispose the client and the message.

Your code should look something like this:

```
var smtp = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
    Port = 587,
    EnableSsl = true,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
};

var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
{
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body,
};

smtp.SendCompleted += (s, e) => {
    SendCompletedCallback(s, e);
    smtp.Dispose();
    message.Dispose();
};
string userState = "Test";
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(Dir));
smtp.SendAsync(message, userState);
```

Comment: @Mordacai1000 Did you take the `message` out of the `using` statement as well? Also, it would be helpful if you could provide the details of the exception.

Comment: I did not remove message. Here is the error :                           System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Mail.MailMessage'.
   at System.Net.Mail.MailMessage.get_AlternateViews()
   at System.Net.Mail.MailMessage.SetContent(Boolean allowUnicode)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.SendMailCallback(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: Thank you very much, wil test it in the morning

Comment: Can anyone here also tell me that whose **dispose()** method should be called first in **SendCompleted** event handler i.e **msg.dispose()** OR **smtpclient.dispose()** ?