# SmtpClient.SendAsync() not sending email if wrapped in using()

Tags: c#, .net-5

I have a .Net5 application and I am trying to send emails using SmtpClient. As I understand it, I should wrap it in a Using statement

So I have the following

```
using(SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(host, port))
{
   ....my code.....
   client.SendAsync(message, userState);
}
```

However this succeeds but I never receive the email.

If I change the code to

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(host, port);
....my code.....
client.SendAsync(message, userState);
```

Then I do receive the email.

I take it that client is being disposed before the email has been sent correctly but then I thought "using" was supposed to handle that properly?

What is the best practice to dispose of client? Also I may need to send multiple emails in using the same code so I need to make sure the client new gets created each time so that I do not dispose of it while it is sending another email.

Comment: You are using `async` functions, but your code doesn't `await`.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/7276819/4694757 `await client.SendAsync(message, userState);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a callback to get the result of the SendAsync call.

Also because you are inside a "using" statement the SmtpClient instance gets disposed before it gets a chance to finish the request.

You get the result of your call like this:

```
    static bool mailSent = false;
    private static void SendCompletedCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the unique identifier for this asynchronous operation.
         String token = (string) e.UserState;

        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
             Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Send canceled.", token);
        }
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
             Console.WriteLine("[{0}] {1}", token, e.Error.ToString());
        } else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message sent.");
        }
        mailSent = true;
    }

        //.... in some other place in the code where your SmptClient lives
        client.SendCompleted += new
        SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);
        // The userState can be any object that allows your callback
        // method to identify this send operation.
        // For this example, the userToken is a string constant.
    
        client.SendAsync(message, userState);
        //wait for the mail to be sent
        while(!mailSent)
        {
        }
```

And basically with SmtpClient the SendAsync works if you do not dispose the instance until **after** the request is over.

Basically you could potentially dispose of the instance in the completed event or by waiting on a boolean for example.

It is not ideal but then again the SmtpClient class is obsolete.

The example was taken directly from Microsoft's documentation [SmtpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-5.0)

Comment: So is there a new method of sending an email? The article seems to suggest using a third party library... Surely .net5 has its own smtp mail sending libraries?

Comment: @coolblue2000 nope. Microsoft has basically deprecated SmtpClient and they will not be implementing a new one. They suggest to use MailKit (and so do I) which is a modern mail client with more bells and whistles than the built in ever had. But you can switch to SendMailAsync which is a Task-returning method that you can await which would solve some of your problems

Comment: Microsoft has basically said thet SmtpClient is obsolete.. I have sience moved to MailKit my self.